# I want to enlarge EditText on click of it

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating android application.  I have already put lot on controls on the screen which occupy lot's of space. In my application i have one editText for searching. SO i resize it which is very small. Now i want on click of edittext or image of search the edittext enlarge. can any one help me out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` for the `EditText`.

Comment: i didn't get you... how sroll related to it can u explain me that? Sorry if my question is silly.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question then. Can you try to be more clear and edit your question. A snap shuold help.

Comment: yes i think the same. just on click of the search image i want edittext to pop up on the screen.

Comment: You could use an Edittext inside a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help u,

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 et.setTextSize(36);
}
```

Comment: Thanks abdul but i want it pop up on the screen

Comment: means, u want onImageClick to produce a new editText field, like popping up,,, so i can say, u can creat new Intent just for editText on ClickListener,
though i haven't go through with popup for editText, but seems possible.